# Convert to set Comprehension

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary-comprehension, for-comprehension

I new to Python and im trying to convert this loop with an if else statement in it to a comprehension but just can't seem to crack it...

Hope you guys can help me?

```
Dict = {'Tim': 18,'Charlie':12,'Tiffany':22,'Robert':25}
Boys = {'Tim': 18,'Charlie':12,'Robert':25}
Girls = {'Tiffany':22}
for key in list(Dict.keys()):
   if key in list(Boys.keys()):
       print(True)
   else:
       print(False)
```

I've tried the following...

```
a = {key for key in list(Dict.keys()) if key in list(Boys.keys())}
b = {key if key in list(Boys.keys()) else False for key in list(Dict.keys())}
c = {key in list(Boys.keys()) if key else False for key in list(Dict.keys())}
print(c)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a `set` comprehension? You aren't creating a set, you are simply printing true or false...

Comment: Also, stop using `list(Dict.keys())` just to iterate over it, that is pointless, because `Dict.keys()` is iterable. But really, you can just iterate over the `dict` object directly, so `for key in Dict:`. But *even more importantly* **do not do** `if key in list(Boys.keys())`, again, `key in Boys.keys()` would work, but really, `key in Boys` is what you want, and using `list(Boys.keys())` instead of the latter two *defeats the purpose of a dict* with fast, hash-based constant time search and devolves to a linear-time search of a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
a = [ True if key in Boys else False  for key in Dict ]
```

should do the trick, you just needed to change the order.

output:

```py
[True, True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be simplified:

```py
c = [key in Boys for key in Dict]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[True, True, False, True]
```

This shows that the first two and the last are boys names.

Also you don't want a `set()` because a set only hold unique values. When the values are `True` and `False`, then a set could only contain 0, 1 or 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need do to get it done,

**1.  Change the order and remove unnecessary list() and keys()**

**2.  Use List Comprehension instead of Dict Comprehension**

```
Dict = {'Tim': 18,'Charlie':12,'Tiffany':22,'Robert':25}
Boys = {'Tim': 18,'Charlie':12,'Robert':25}  
a = [True if key in Boys.keys else False for key in Dict]
print(a)
```